# Facebook pmd system: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, pmd

We are developing a Facebook PMD system,but when we upload the link through API,we get this error:'Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains' .
We did what people say: add link in Site URL and the issue was solved.
But since we are a PMD system,it should allow different users to add different links in our system.But 'Site URL' can only add one link.
What should we do?

Answer (score 0):

You can only use one Site URL per App. Subdomains will work too (you can just add the topl level domain to the App Domains), but you can´t use different domains with for the same App....if that´s what you are trying to do. Your customers would need to create their own App for that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.We are a Facebook Marketing Partner,we are building a system to help users to optimize their campaigns,this will need users to create their campaigns on our system totally.There must have different domains,how can we associate our app with their own apps in this case?

Comment: well, you can´t. they can´t use YOUR app on THEIR server with THEIR domain.